# Visual Studio not showing errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio 2015 and it all of a sudden stopped showing the red squiggly lines under errors.  For example, the following code does not get any errors:

```
Double* test = new int(10);
double test = new int(10);
double test = new int(10)
```

Nothing about a double pointer that's pointing to an int, nothing about multiple variable names being the same.

I've checked Tools / Options / Text Editor / C++ / General -- the "auto list members" and "parameter information" boxes are checked.

Also under Tools / Options / Text Editor / All Languages the "auto list members", "hide advanced members", and "parameter information" boxes are checked

...What settings do I need to change?

Comment: Dis you create a project?

Comment: Yes, I did a new empty project.  I am writing my own templated class so everything is defined in the header file.  Would that affect it?

Comment: I have seen this frequently.  Some combination of Rebuild All, closing and reloading the solution, closing and reloading Visual Studio, and/or logging out and logging back in usually gets it going again.  I suspect some background thread or process gets stuck trying to modify its model of the code as the code changes, and somehow gets out of sync.  Getting everything restarted lets it rebuild the model from scratch and the red squigglies return.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: ↓↓↓↓↓↓

Comment: @BoundaryImposition:  I'm not sure how to interpret your comment.  Are signaling that you would vote it down if there were such an option?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: No, I'm pointing you to the answer section! :)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: I didn't think it useful enough without more specificity.  I'm not sure which of those steps actually solves the problem nor whether my hypothesis is even correct.

Comment: @Adrian: Even more reason to post it in a place where it can be peer reviewed appropriately. The comments section is for requesting clarification. Thanks

Comment: Turns out it was just the fact that I was using a templated class so the compiler wasn't able to detect errors